# doxygen: how do I document \enum values out-of-line?

Tags: c++, enums, doxygen

To be precise: I know how to dox enums at the point of declaration, I want to dox them out-of-line instead.

I want to keep the header file free of doxygen comments; they're all in the .cpp file. This is not a problem for functions, classes, typedefs and so on. I can also document the `enum` itself like this:

```
/*!
  \enum MyClass::MyEnum

  Foo Bar Baz

  \value FirstEnumValue <- doesn't work
*/
```

but how do I document the *values* of the `enum` there?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use \var according to the [docs](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdenum)